# Mapping from a discrete metric space

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

I came across this problem in MIT course archives. I am currently trying to learn real analysis and the problem is as follows:

> Let $(S, d_S )$ be a discrete metric such that $d_S(t, r) = 1;\ \forall t \ne r)$
>   (a) Show that any map $f : S\to X$ into another metric space $X$ is continuous; using the definition of continuity by sequences.
>   (b) Show that any map $f : S\to X$ into another metric space $X$ is continuous; using the definition of continuity by $\epsilon\delta$-balls.
>   (c) Which maps $f : \mathbb R\to S$ are continuous? (Give an easy characterization and prove it.)

**My attempt:**
**A.** Fix a point $x_\circ\in X$. Define a sequence $S=\{x_n\}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_\circ$ It follows $f(x_n)\in f(S);\forall \ n\in \mathbb{N}$. $S$ is open.
If I can prove $f(S)$ is open, it would imply $f$ is continuous. If $f(S)$ doesn't contain{how do you write this in MathJax} $f(x_\circ)$, it is open. Correspondingly, $S$ is open. Hence, $f:S\to X$ is continuous.

**B.** Here is my argument using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. Fix a point $x_\circ$. $d_S(p,x_\circ)=1<\delta\ \ \forall \ \ p\ne x_\circ\in S$. We can pick $\epsilon=\sup\{d_X(f(x),f(x_\circ)\}$

**C.** My guess is only constant functions will be continuous.

Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A.** Proving that $f(S)$ is open prove nothing. If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x_0$ in $S$ then there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies d(x_n,x_0)<1$. Therefore,$$n\geqslant N\implies x_n=x_0\implies f(x_n)=f(x_0)\iff d\bigl(f(x_n),f(x_0)\bigr)=0.$$So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$.

**B.** Let $\varepsilon>0$ and take $\delta=1$. Then$$d(x,x_0)<\delta\iff x=x_0\implies d\bigl(f(x),f(x_0)\bigr)=0<\varepsilon.$$

**C.** Yes, only constant functions will be continuous. That's because $\mathbb R$ is connected and therefore $f(\mathbb R)$ is connected too. But the only non-empty connected subsets of a discrete metric space are the singletons.

Comment: Thanks.
Regarding part A, that's what confused me about this particular metric. We either have $d=1$ or $d=0$. Therefore, we can't really argue that for $n\in \mathbb{N}, d_S(x_n,x_\circ)<1$ as far as I understand, right? For example, say $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. But for no value of $n$, will we have $d_S(x_n,x_\circ)<1$. Please help me with this.

Comment: Yes, we can have $d(x_n,x_0)<1$. It holds when and only when $x_n=x_0$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it occurs for $x_n=x_\circ$ but what I am confused about is whether we can really argue for the fact that $x_n$ will equal $x_\circ$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Like in the sequence I gave for example, no value of $n\in \mathbb{N}$ will satisfy $x_n=x_\circ$.

Comment: Indeed. With respect to the discrete metric, we have $\left(\forall n\in\mathbb N\right):d\left(\frac1n,0\right)=1$ and therefore, with respect to the discrete metric, we *don't* have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$.

Comment: Ah. Thanks a lot. So let me know if I got this right. $d_S(\frac{1}{n},0)=1$, hence, in this particular metric we cannot argue that $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is converging to $0$. And any sequence that will actually converge in this metric space will definitely achieve the value of $x_\circ$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is that Correct? Thanks for your help/

Comment: Yes. With respect to the discrete metric, a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x_0$ if and only if the equality $x_n=x_0$ holds if $n$ is large enough.